# MonoGame OpenGL File Not Found Error

Tags: xna, monogame

I just started using MonoGame, and I made a new project in Xamarian Studio(my IDE of choice). This is the error I get:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MonoGame.Framework, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.   at TUTORIAL.Program.Main()
>   The application exited with code: -532462766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce this issue with the following steps:

- Download [MonoGame 3.0.1 for Xamarin Studio](http://monogame.codeplex.com/downloads/get/632972)
- Install the mpack file into Xamrain Studio using Tools -> Addin Manager -> Install from file
- Create a new solution and choose the MonoGame Windows OpenGL Application template

I may have also previously installed [MonoGame 3.0.1 for Visual Studio 2010/2012](http://monogame.codeplex.com/downloads/get/632970). I'm not sure if that's a required step but it could be. Check to see if you have a C:\Program Files\MonoGame\v3.0 folder on your machine and if not you make also need to install that.

Comment: If you are using MonoGame you shouldn't need XNA at all. Check the project references and remove any related to XNA.